# Why does CO2 cause heating in troposphere but cooling mesosphere?

Tags: troposphere

Why does CO2 cause heating in troposphere but cooling mesosphere?
Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I recommend reading this paper: https://www.earth-syst-dynam.net/7/697/2016/esd-7-697-2016.pdf Quote: (i) the blocking effect, associated with a cooling due to the fact that CO2 absorbs
radiation at wavelengths where the atmosphere is already relatively opaque, and (ii) the indirect solar effect,
associated with a cooling in places where an additional (solar) heating term is present (which on Earth is particularly
the case in the upper parts of the ozone layer).

Comment: Hi Sachin, how much do you know about radiative transfer? Do you know what an optically thick/thin transition is? Just to establish what your previous knowledge is.